# NSWorkspace selectFile:inFileViewerRootedAtPath: does not work the first time it is called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, finder, nsworkspace

I have a sandboxed Cocoa app. I noticed that when I call `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:path inFileViewerRootedAtPath:path]` no Finder window opens the first time is called. Finder.app is brought to the foreground (menu bar changes to Finder), but otherwise nothing happens.

When I bring my app back to the front and again have it select a file in Finder, the Finder window opens with the file selected as expected. I tried this with `@""` as second argument, same thing.

When a Finder window is open already, everything works as expected.

Has anybody else seen this problem? Workaround is to immediately call `selectFile:...` twice, but that doesn't seem right.

Edit: not related to sandboxing. Same issue without sandbox.

Comment: are you getting this problem in 10.8?

Comment: @ParagBafna Problem happens on 10.7.4

Comment: for me its not working on 10.8.2

Comment: Ditto, I think I'm about to give up on my Reveal in Finder functionality. Both `activateFileViewerSelectingURLs:` and `selectFile:inFileViewerRootedAtPath:` do nothing for me on 10.8.2.

Answer (score 2):

I think activateFileViewerSelectingURLs is better. It correctly selects multiple files in the finder.